# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...functions.php on line 70

Tags: php, warnings

I get this error to the following code snippet:

```
foreach( $all_metas as $key => $value_array ) {
        $value[ $key ] = $value_array[0];
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check what `$all_metas` is, since it's clearly not iterable.

Comment: If you're unsure how to do that, I recommend the [beginner's guide to debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/).

Comment: The warning (not error!) means that `$all_metas` is not an array or anything else you can loop over. So please debug your code and find out why `$all_metas` did not contain what you expected, and then fix it.

Comment: $all_metas = get_post_meta( $object_id, '', true );

Comment: You might want to read the [manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for that function and see what supplying `true` as the third parameter does.

Answer (score -1):

Print $all_metas variable first. It is not getting array value in $all_metas. May be string is stored in the variable $all_metas.